# How to add a Favicon to RSS feeds using Wordpress?

Tags: wordpress, rss, favicon, google-reader

A friend of mine wants to make her favicon visible when people user Google Reader to view the RSS of her Wordpress blog. Anyone have a quick tip on how / where to make that reference? Her current web host is Bluehost, and apparently that is the "icon" people see when using Google Reader. Any suggestions would be helpful.

Comment: This is not programming related. It should be moved to Super User.

Comment: It is programming. You define your site's favicon in a number of ways - on the server root, via <meta> tags in the code, etc. I wanted to know if there was a specific way to do it so that it shows up as part of RSS feeds in GReader. If anything, based on the solution, this is more ServerFault related.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a user preference - according to the Google Reader docs - and it doesn't always work: [Bug report: favicons for subscriptions are not always displayed - Google Reader Help](http://www.google.com/support/forum/p/reader/thread?tid=02866ed2b2a0dba0&hl=en)

Comment: So, at the very least, his friend should make sure that the favicon is at the webroot and not linked in the theme head.

Comment: Perfect. +100 for the link :)